# Backbone.Collection.create() using Collection.url and not Model.url

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I'm trying to create model objects on the fly using Backbone.Collection.create...but I note that the collection uses its url and not the model's url...

Is this how it suppose to work? Can I override it on the fly just for this particular .create()?

Comment: Have a look at [urlroot](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `options` attribute that contain the `url` property :

```
Backbone.Collection.create({
  key: "value",
  ...
}, { url : 'yourUrlHere' });
```

Comment: I was trying this but it doesn't seem to override it

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for your problem ?